# How to find all words that start with an uppercase letter using Python Regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex, file, python-re, findall

Below is the code to find all upper case words from a file and add them to a list, how can I change this so that only words that start with an upper case are added to the list.

```
import re

matches = []
regex = r"\b[A-Z]\w*"
filename = r'C:\Users\Documents\romeo.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        matches += re.findall(regex, line)
print(matches)
```

File:

```
Hello, How are YOU
```

Output:

```
[Hello,How]
```

YOU should not be included in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` matches both upper and lower case letters, as well as numbers and underscores. If you only want to match lower case letters, specify it like this:

```py
regex = r"\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b"
text = 'Hello, How are YOU'
re.findall(pattern, text) # ['Hello', 'How']
```

Have a look at the Python regular expression syntax in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) to learn about other options.